# Remove lines from hosts file when same line exist in whitelist.txt VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two text files **hosts** file and **whitelist.txt**

**hosts**

```
google.com
facebook.com
x.com
y.com
z.com
youtube.com
duckduckgo.com
stackoverflow.com
w.com
```

**whitelist.txt**

```
w.com
x.com
y.com
z.com
```

when i click a button, The lines in **whitelist.txt** must be removed from **hosts** file

ex: **x.com** is in **whitelist.txt** so it should be removed from **hosts** file

**Expected output :**
**hosts**

```
google.com
facebook.com
youtube.com
duckduckgo.com
stackoverflow.com
```

The **hosts** file will be comparatively a big file > 3-6 MB.

It will be a big process.

No need to remove same lines from both file. Only from **hosts** file.

**Edit**

```
Public Sub RemoveLines(file1path As String, file2path As String)
        Dim s1 As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1path)
        Dim s2 As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file2path)
        Dim l As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) l.AddRange(s1.ToList) l.AddRange(s2.ToList) 
        If s1.ToList = s2.ToList Then
            RemoveLines = s1.text
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Please provide "any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem”. See [Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Comment: Hai @pointum please help. What i need is lines in file1 should be removed from file2. I don't know coding. Also my English is bad. Nobody is helping me.

Comment: you deleted a previous post, but i got solution there with .net core 3.0, is ot OK?

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Comment: @ArturMustafin yes. I don't know it will be a problem. I'm working in .net 4.5.2. Anyway please answer. Thank you.

Comment: @yoyoyoyoyo OK, ready an go)

Comment: @Haldo `    Public Sub RemoveLines(file1path As String, file2path As String)
        Dim s1 As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1path)
        Dim s2 As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file2path)
        Dim l As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        l.AddRange(s1.ToList)
        l.AddRange(s2.ToList)
        If
                s1.ToList = s2.ToList
            RemoveLines = s1.text
    End Sub`

Comment: @ArturMustafin can you do it in c#. I'll try to convert it to vb.net. I don't know how to add the below code in my application. Please help me

Comment: I vote to close because this is clearly a duplicate of the post that you recently deleted and does not show any effort or research at providing a solution in the first place. In the previous post I pointed you towards the [tour], [ask] and that you should provide a [mcve]. None of which you seem to have heeded.

Comment: Please don't post more than a bit of code in a comment. I edited you question and added the code there. As we know, that code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub sample project filter-lines](https://github.com/hack2root/filter-lines)

From the previously deleted post, my way of doing this, is to:

1. Load 2 files as line arrays in memory (List);
2. Create 2 hashsets for each file
3. Create hash entry for each line in a file, (hash, line)
4. Compute MD5 hash of each string, write half of bits (64 bit) to hash
5. Extract keys from each hash pair (hash,_)
6. Extract lines with filtered criteria (keys2 do not contains hash of current line)
7. Write result to file

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace filter_lines
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var md5 = MD5.Create();
            var hashes = new HashSet<long>();
            (long, string) Hash(string input, Encoding encoding = null)
            {
                var bytes = (Span<byte>)stackalloc byte[encoding.GetByteCount(input)];
                var destination = (Span<byte>)stackalloc byte[md5.HashSize / 8];
                encoding.GetBytes(input, bytes);
                return md5.TryComputeHash(bytes, destination, out int _bytesWritten)
                    ? (BitConverter.ToInt64(destination.ToArray()), input) : (0, null);
            }
            async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ReadFileAsync(string fileName) =>
                await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(fileName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var dict1 = await ReadFileAsync(args[0]).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var dict2 = await ReadFileAsync(args[1]).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var hashes1 = dict1.Select(_ => Hash(_, Encoding.UTF8));
            var hashes2 = dict2.Select(_ => Hash(_, Encoding.UTF8));
            var keys1 = new HashSet<long>(hashes1.Select(_ => _.Item1));
            var keys2 = new HashSet<long>(hashes2.Select(_ => _.Item1));
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            File.WriteAllLines(args[0], hashes1
                .Where(_ => !keys2.Contains(_.Item1))
                .Select(_ => _.Item2));
            stopwatch.Watch();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public static class StopwatchExtensions
    {
        public static void Watch(this Stopwatch stopwatch, string message = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) =>
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"{stopwatch.Elapsed} " +
            $"{message} " +
            $"{memberName} " +
            $"{sourceFilePath}:{sourceLineNumber}");
    }
}
```

Results: 44ms for filtering test 1000000 lines of all.txt

[image: 44ms - 1000000 lines of all.txt, .NET Core 3.0, C# 8.0]

Comment: Mine is a windows forms application. Not console application. Anyway, i'll try this.

Comment: @yoyoyoyoyo This is a bits from my project, you can try if it solves your problem: /******/



https://github.com/hack2root/filter-lines

Comment: I don't know how to add this code in my application. It'll be nice if it is in VB.net forms. Is its possible to convert ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Imports System.IO` File class to retrieve the data.

A `StringBuilder` requires `Imports System.Text` at the top of the file. The `StringBuilder` save the code from creating and a new `String` every time a string changes. (Strings are immutable) `.ReadAllLines` returns an array of the lines in the text file.

Loop through each line in hosts.txt and check if that line `.Exists` in the array of lines from whitelist.txt. If it doesn't exist, add it to the `StringBuilder`.

Finally, change the `StringBuilder` to a `String` and write all the text to hosts.txt with the `File.WriteAllText` method.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim linesFromHost = File.ReadAllLines("hosts.txt") 'You will need to add the full path 
    Dim linesFromWhiteList = File.ReadAllLines("whitelist.txt")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each line As String In linesFromHost
        'If the line from linesFromHost is not found in the linesFromWhiteList then add it to the StringBuilder
        If Not Array.Exists(linesFromWhiteList, Function(x) x = line) Then
            sb.AppendLine(line)
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllText("hosts.txt", sb.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

I am sure the code presented by @ArturMustafin is much faster but this might get you started.